# Loop through the dropdown list and check if any <option> has a specific class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui

```html
<ul tabindex="-1" class="k-list k-reset" id="ddlEngineer_listbox" role="listbox" aria-hidden="true" aria-live="off" data-role="staticlist" unselectable="on">
  <li tabindex="-1" class="k-item k-state-selected" role="option" aria-selected="true" unselectable="on" data-offset-index="0">[Unassigned]</li>
  <li tabindex="-1" class="k-item" role="option" aria-selected="false" unselectable="on" data-offset-index="1">DANIEL RUSSELL</li>
  <li tabindex="-1" class="k-item" role="option" aria-selected="false" unselectable="on" data-offset-index="2">MELODY CAPONE</li>
  <li tabindex="-1" class="k-item k-state-selected k-state-focused" id="040e59b0-8d21-4368-8ea2-2bc1c4153133" role="option" aria-selected="true" unselectable="on" data-offset-index="3">[Show All]</li>
</ul>
```

I have the above html code,

Using Jquery I want to loop through the dropdown and check if any of the option has a CSS class whose name contains 'focused' so that I can replace it to some other class. And also change the property 'area-selected' to false

So far I have tried this...

```
$("#ddlEngineer option").each(function(i){
var v=$('select[name="ddlEngineer"] option:selected').attr('class');
if(v.Contains("focused"))
{
$(this).addClass("k-item");

}
)};
```

But it doesn't seem to work as I see `$('select[name="ddlEngineer"] option:selected').attr('class')` having `undefined` value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in a much more simple way:

```
$.fn.handleDropDown = function() {
    let $option = $(this).find("option.focused");

    if ($option.length) {
        $option
            .toggleClass("focused some-other-class") // remove the 'focused' class and add 'some-other-class'
            .attr("aria-selected", "false"); // change the value of 'aria-selected' attribute
    }
};

$("#ddlEngineer").handleDropDown();
```

Although I highly advise you to avoid changing properties' values of a kendo widget like that. Whatever you want to achieve in your widget, it probably have a better - and semantic - way to do.

Comment: I tried your code, the $option is always undefined even though there is a class with a word 'focused' in its class name. My options' class is something like  'k-item k-focused'. So I wonder if your code is searching for a an exclusive class named 'focused'

Comment: @Shekar.gvr well, then try something like `$(this).find("option.focused, option.k-focused");`